# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (nimages > 0) in calibrateCamera, , line 3415 by python

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I am doing camera calibration in ubuntu 14 using OpenCV with python

I executed the code attached with this post for camera calibration. A part of the code seems to work properly as the camera detected the corners properly. But there was this error "**OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (nimages > 0) in calibrateCamera, file /home/aljovjoy/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp, line 3415 "**

This error should be rectified to complete the camera calibration.Please tell me how to remove this error to make it work

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
objpoints = []
imgpoints = [] 
images = glob.glob('/usr/local/share/OpenCV/samples/cpp/chess*.jpg')
for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret = False
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (9,6))
    if ret == True:
        cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)
        # Draw and display the corners
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), corners, ret)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the code is complete?  I ran the code and didn't see any errors. The corners were detected in the chessboard. That's all the code you posted above does. Check the file path if you still get an error.